# tex4ht: Cannot compile document with \vref command

Tags: tex4ht, varioref

I use `tex4ht` to compile my document.

In case if I use  `\vref` command  in my document, compilation fails with error:

```
Undefined control sequence
```

How to handle this situation?

Comment: Either this is a feature of `tex4ht` or you should show us what you have done so far

Comment: We really need a `mwe` in this case, package `varioref` is supported by `tex4ht` and I've got no error in sample document with `\vref` command

Comment: I made i little investigation, and it looks like if I use \usepackage{hyperref} and \usepackage{varioref}, compilation fails, otherwise if I use only \usepackage{varioref} compilation is successfull. However I need both packages.

Comment: It does seem to be a combination of the hyperref and varioref packages that causes the problem. I would also like to use both, but if I don't use varioref, then the problem goes away...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it seems that there is an issue between `hyperref` and `varioref` with `tex4ht`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{varioref}
% \let\vref\ref

\begin{document}
\section{first}\label{section}

See~\vref{section}


And \vpageref{section}. 
And a range: \vrefrange{section}{second}

\section{second}\label{second}
\end{document}
```

This fails with nice error message:

```
(./sample.aux)
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
<inserted text> 
                macro:->
l.9 See~\vref{section}
```

the issue seems to be caused because of clash between all three packages in way they write label information to the aux file. I don't know a system solution, but as a fix, we can just redefine `\vref` and `\vpageref` as ordinary `\ref` and `\pageref`. You will lost the `on page` part, but as in `html` there are no page numbers, it doesn't make sense anyway.

Try this `.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\makeatletter
\let\vr@f\ref
\let\vp@geref\pageref
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

incidentally, `\vrefrange` seems to work without redefinition. This is a result with the configuration:

[image]